# Witcher 2 ff_damage

Tags: mods, the-witcher-2

I am looking through the witcher 2 configuration files that specify which stats Geralt gains upon leveling up. Here is an example for each level gained:

```
<ability name="Level2" on_added="" on_ended="">
        <vitality mult="false" always_random="false" min="5" max="5"/>
        <ff_damage_min mult="false" always_random="false" min="3" max="3"/>
        <ff_damage_max mult="false" always_random="false" min="5" max="5"/>         
</ability>
```

Does anyone know what might this *ff_damage* be? The vitality increases normally by 5 as specified each level. I looked at this and I didn't see an increase in normal damage in character screen so ff_damage must be something else.

Comment: I could see FF being an acronym for something specific to the Polish language, which means that it would be beneficial to ask someone fluent what would be useful to abbreviate FF with respect to game skills. ALTERNATIVELY, if you set the game language to polish, is any stat labeled such that it is two words that both start with F ?

Comment: I don't think so. No stat in the game gets a +3-5 damage each level. At least not one that is displayed in the interface.